# MVVM Light Send Message from 1 view to another

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am using the MVVM Light with an WPF Application that I would like to use the messenger feature to pass some values from one viewmodel to another viewmodel.

LoginViewModel.cs

```
MessengerInstance.Send<int>(CID);
```

OrderViewModel.cs

```
 MessengerInstance.Register<int>(this, x => { MessageBox.Show(x.ToString()); });
```

The orderviewmodel needs that integer but when printout the value of x, it is 0. With this example given, the Messagebox does not even be seen. It skips right over the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending:

```
Messenger.Default.Send<int>(CID);
```

Receiving

```
 Messenger.Default.Register<int>(
this, <int>(this, x => { MessageBox.Show(x.ToString()); }));
```

Keep in mind that Registering needs to be set before any message is sent. Messages are not queued. Extensive description [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx).